# How to specify altitude for a circle or symbol layer in Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, altitude, 3d-mapping

I have two layers built on `FeatureCollection` GeoJSON data. One of them is of type `circle` and the other is `symbol`. Here they are:

[image]

Thing is, as you can see in our project we use 3D buildings on the map, and we need our objects to be at a certain altitude above the ground. The question is, **how to do this in Mapbox?**

Here's what I've tried:

#### GeoJSON feature coordinates

> An OPTIONAL third-position element SHALL    be the height in meters
> above or below the WGS 84 reference    ellipsoid.  In the absence of
> elevation values, applications    sensitive to height or depth SHOULD
> interpret positions as being at    local ground or sea level.
> — [GeoJSON spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-4).

I've tried setting the third argument for a feature's geometry, which is a point, but it didn't help. Looks like the third value is just being ignored.

```
      return {
        type: 'Feature',
        id: l.id,
        geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [l.coordinates.lng, l.coordinates.lat, 50]
        }
      }
```

#### [`circle-translate`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-circle-circle-translate)

> The geometry's offset. Values are [x, y] where negatives indicate left and up, respectively.

I've tried setting this but the result looked super weird, it didn't look like a normal elevation.

#### Example

I've modified an example from Mapbox so you can play around with this — [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zncvetxd/3/).

Comment: circle-translate is the way to handle the offset, you should play with the circle-pitch-alignment, circle-pitch-scale, and circle-translate-anchor to see if that helps.  I think the issue you'll run into is that the circle layer will produce a flat vector graphic, you'll have better luck using the symbol layer with custom icons.  This will allow you to create a hover effect by messing with symbol offset and pitch along with the label anchor and pitch, combined with a custom icon graphic to show depth (3d orb)

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for setting elevation on symbol layers. See https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3993 and https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10483

Comment: Bad news :( So now workarounds for this or some other libraries on top of Mapbox? I've tried looking for them, but couldn't find anything myself.